# return dictionary leak cause crash

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, ios4

I have a confusion for me about property object like this

```
NSMutableDictionary* spradSettingValueByLinkcode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary * spradSettingValueByLinkcode;
```

and then synthesize in .m file like

```
@synthesize spradSettingValueByLinkcode =   _spradSettingValueByLinkcode;
```

then i am using the property for setting the value return by a function like that

```
_spradSettingValueByLinkcode = (NSMutableDictionary*)[_dbObject initWithSpraderSetting:inputLinkcode];
```

well the issue is

1) i assign but property not retain when i use the dictionary into table view

2) if i allocate

```
_spradSettingValueByLinkcode = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[_dbObject initWithSpraderSetting:inputLinkcode]];
```

then i can't release because app get crash and if i not release then memory leak

so below code which if working for me is perfect but not looking right to me so i need to ask am i doing right or wrong?

```
// This Method use for Load View of SpreaderSettings
- (void) loadSpreaderSettingsValues:(NSString*)inputLinkcode {

    [_spradSettingValueByLinkcode removeAllObjects]; 
    if (!_dbObject) [self loadDBAccessDatabase];

    [_spradSettingValueByLinkcode release]; // relase the previos retain object to maintain count 1
    _spradSettingValueByLinkcode = (NSMutableDictionary*)[_dbObject initWithSpraderSetting:inputLinkcode];
    [_spradSettingValueByLinkcode retain];
    [_productAnalysisTitleLabel setTitle:[_spradSettingValueByLinkcode objectForKey:@"description"]];
    [_TBSpreaderSetting reloadData];
}

- (DBAccess *) loadDBAccessDatabase {
    // NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    _dbObject = [DBAccess sharedDBObjectAccess];
    return _dbObject;
}
```

Comment: Is there any *useful* message printed when the app crashes ?

Comment: can you explain `[_dbObject initWithSpraderSetting:inputLinkcode]`? why not something like `[[SomeClass alloc] initWithSpraderSetting:inputLinkcode]`

Comment: crash log is normal like CFDictionay object is deallocated?and for _dbObject its a shared object and i am using in other contrller also.

Comment: I understand the process like mydbclass return an autorelease dictionary and my property object try to retain it else object get release but even i allocate the object with dictionary and use auto release, app also get crash, so i thought because this method call several times so first i relse the object then allocate but i think it's very bad

Comment: I want to ask one question more that, i have one property like array and we usually release at dealloc method, so if i have one function who called number of times and i use [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: (array)] so the object count always increase? i know that when an event complete dealloc method call but is this a right way to use code?